# I am trying to click on a button which has the following html structure: Not able to click the button "English". It says no such element. Tried Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Could not click the button English.
It says no such element exists.

Tried the following and Select method.

```js
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/content/main/div/form")))
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for='language-MCQ'] span[class='me-2']"))
```

2. Code block:

```html
<input class="form-check-input d-none lang-list" type="checkbox" id="language-MCQ" name="language_ids[]" value="1" wire:model="language_ids.0" wire:change="addLanguageQuestions(1)">
<label class="form-check-label d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center rounded-pill btn btn-lg btn-lang-select text-white cursor-pointer" for="language-MCQ">
   <span class="me-2">
       English
   </span>
</label>
<div class="form-check ps-0 me-3">
                            <input class="form-check-input d-none lang-list" type="checkbox" id="language-Kannada" name="language_ids[]" value="2" wire:model="language_ids.1" wire:change="addLanguageQuestions(2)">
                            <label class="form-check-label d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center rounded-pill btn btn-lg btn-lang-select text-white cursor-pointer" for="language-Kannada">
                                <span class="me-2">
                                    Kannada
                                </span>

                            </label>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Show us html structure of page and do not add it as image, if site is public then share the url

Comment: My First time asking a question. Did not know how to add the code. next time won't add an image. I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: Read [tour] and [mcve] you will get to know  most of the things.

Comment: what kind of button it is, It looks like checkbox with label English? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's a checkbox type. There are 3 buttons. One is English.

Comment: Try this xpath `//input[@id='language-MCQ']//span[contains(text(),'English')]` or `//span[contains(text(),'English')]`

Comment: @ShwethaA does it worked in the answers below, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this xpath :

```
//span[text()='English']
```

if you do not wish to use `text()`

```
//label[@for='language-MCQ']/span
```

also this looks wrong

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("label[for='language-MCQ'] span[class='me-2']"))
```

Note that Select is only applicable for html select tag.

Comment: I tried that. It did not work. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Is page url public ?

Comment: URL is not public

Comment: okay I understand that, can you look for iframe ? It could be in iframe ?

Comment: once I click the button, it opens a field after that selection.  then the iframe shows up.  <iframe id="mce_33_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-F9 for menu. Press ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"></iframe>

Comment: Which button you meant ? English one ? also see in the dev tool if your desired element is wrapped into an iframe. if it is, then you'd have to switch first to iframe.

Comment: The English button is as shown in the code snippet. Once I click the English it opens a field to type in English (that part has an iframe).

Comment: okay then it's not in iframe, also do you see double quotes around English in HTML structure ? something like `"English"` ?

Comment: No <span class="me-2">
                                    English
                                </span>

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste  and see `//span[text()='English']` if your desired element is getting highlighted

Comment: see if we have 1/1 matching node ?

Comment: It did not match

Comment: hmmm, if it did not match then we have issue with xpath. does this have any match `//label[@for='language-MCQ']` ?

Comment: Yes , it matches with <label class="form-check-label d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center rounded-pill btn btn-lg btn-lang-select text-white cursor-pointer" for="language-MCQ">
                                <span class="me-2">
                                    English
                                </span>

                            </label>

Comment: @cruisepandey `/span[text()='English']` it seems there is space surrounded to English text

Comment: Even selection through Visible text did not work .

Comment: if this matches `//label[@for='language-MCQ']` then try `//label[@for='language-MCQ']/span` should match too, do they have 1/1 matching node ? if yes then try to directly click on that.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the possibility of any kind of exception it is recommended that your xpath should be pointed to the interactive element, In this case `span` or `label` is not interactive element but the `input` tag.

and your possible xpath solutions can be -

```
.//span[contains(text(),'English')]/ancestor::label/preceding-sibling::input
```

Or

```
.//input[@id='language-MCQ']
```

Or

```
.//label[contains(@class,'btn-lang-select')]/preceding-sibling::input[@value='1']
```

something like this should work -

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//span[contains(text(),'English')]/ancestor::label/preceding-sibling::input")))

element.click()
```

If the above xpaths are not working with the explicit wait and expected conditions then check element should be in iframe.